# Clarifications for proof that $S_4 / V \cong S_3$ with $V=\{e,(12)(34),(13)(24),(14)(23)\}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm trying to understand the proof for $S_4 / V \cong S_3$ .  with $V=\{e,(12)(34),(13)(24),(14)(23)\}$

The proof goes as follows. I will write comments next to each step as to what I'm trying to understand:

1. $V \trianglelefteq S_4$
   (Is this because of the cycle structure of elements of $V$?. Meaning, there are no elements in $S_4$ that contain the same cycle type, each having the same elements in the cycles.)
2. $ V \cap S_3 = {e}$  (This is clear)
3. $ S_3V = S_4$ (Why? Of course i can get this by calculating everything. But there must be a better way of making this observation)
4. $S_3V/V \cong S_3/S_3 \cap V$ (2nd Isomorphism theorem)

Clarification would be much appreciated for points 1 and 3, as well as general tips around the intuition around these sorts of tasks. I'm having a lot of difficulty with the symmetric group.

Comment: What subgroup is $V$?

Comment: The klein 4 group. Apologies! Updating it now!

Comment: Which Klein 4 group? There are several to choose from. Presumably they all yield the same result, but it ought to be specified.

Comment: Added more details :)

Comment: I realized they do not all give the same result. We also have $\{e, (12), (34), (12)(34)\}$ as a copy of the Klein-4 group, and that is certainly not normal. So it's good that you specified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes, it is because conjugate elements have the same cyclic structure. Here $V=\{1, (12)(34),(13)(24), (14)(23)\}$ and no other element of $S_4$ has cyclic structure $(ab)(cd)$.
2. $|S_3V|=|S_3||V|=24=|S_4|$ so $S_3V=S_4$.

Comment: Why would 2. necessarily hold just because the orders form the order of $S_4$?

Comment: @Hristmar That's a bug in the enumeration. They actually mean 3, not 2, but this site won't allow you to skip a number when you itemize like that.

Comment: If a subset of an $n$-element set has $n$ elements then it is the whole set.

Comment: Understood. Thank you!